# Shift focus to next EditText in another RecyclerView item (CardView)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, focus, cardview

I am using a RecyclerView to a hold a bunch of CardViews, which contain an EditText. The user should edit the text and continue to the next CardView by clicking the "continue/finished" button on the soft keyboard. While the next EditText gets focused the soft keyboard should stay opened. The card views are as wide as the phone's screen and need to be scrolled horizontally / from right to left.
My code can already identify a "continue" button click but I am stuck at shifting the focus.
Please let me know if this is possible and if it is how. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is by adding a method to your class extending RecyclerView.ViewHolder.

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public CardView mCardView;
    public EditText mEditText;
    public MyViewHolder(CardView v) {
        super(v);
        mCardView = v;
        mEditText = v.findViewById(R.id.mEditText);
    }

    public void takeFocus() {
        if (mEditText != null && mEditText.isShown()) {
            mEditText.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on if there are other ViewHolder classes that you are using, you would likely want to add some logic such as mViewHolder instanceOf MyViewHolder before calling the takeFocus() method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

First I have to scroll to the item from the recycler view and then invoke the `requestFocus()` method of the edit text. 
To prevent the soft keyboard/IME I used the `InputMethodManager` to forcibly show the IME.